# Reading Serilog logs stored in a database

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, serilog

I'm writing a dotnet core application that uses Entity Framework Core and Serilog. I would like to store the logs in a Postgres Database (SQLite when debugging)

I want to be able to pull out the logs from the database through the application so it can be presented in a readable manner, (filtered and searched) but I'm having a hard time finding references to how Serilog stores its data, (I can't even tell if it depends entirely on the Sink, which I suspect it does) which makes me think I'm approaching this problem from the wrong angle.

So if I want to be able to pull out Serilog's logs from a database, (Postgres, but preferably any arbitrary database, if it's possible) how should I go about it?

Comment: See folloiwing : https://docs.datalust.co/docs/using-serilog.  There is a github for this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serilog relies on a sink to know how what to do with the data, using a sink like: serilog.sinks.postgresql would handle writing to the database for you, then you'd have to make your own solution for querying and parsing the logs once theyre written.

Link for that sink here: https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql

Comment: I sorta figured. I was just hoping there was a standard way of extracting the data again. But the IDictionary columnWriters in the example seems to the table, so I'll have to go with that as a base. You wouldn't happen to also have an example on how to configure the tables in appsettings.json would you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's one of the few sinks I've not really used much myself (only come in contact with it when working in other peoples codebases), but I believe you cant directly use AppSettings, you need to use the serilog.settings.configuration package to allow you to define a json settings file